# Manipulating subindex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

Let us generate the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
np.random.seed(42)
mi = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1]],
             labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6], 
                     [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
             names=['day_of_week', 'cat'])
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,size=14), mi, ['count'])
```

[image]

I would like to add a column which will hold the ratios between the values for each `(day_of_week, cat)` and the sum of the two values for the `day_of_week`. For example, the first two rows of the needed column would be: `[52/(52+93), 93/(52+93),...]`

I know how to compute the sum for each day: `X.sum(level=0)`, but I don't know how to proceed. I could iterate and loop my way out, but this won't be pythonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by level `day_of_week` with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new `Series` with same `index` as original `df`:

```
print (X.groupby(level='day_of_week')['count'].transform('sum'))
day_of_week  cat
0            0      145
             1      145
1            0       87
             1       87
2            0       82
             1       82
3            0      170
             1      170
4            0      150
             1      150
5            0      112
             1      112
6            0       25
             1       25
Name: count, dtype: int32
X['ratio'] = X['count'].div(X.groupby(level='day_of_week')['count'].transform('sum'))
print (X)
                 count     ratio
day_of_week cat                 
0           0       52  0.358621
            1       93  0.641379
1           0       15  0.172414
            1       72  0.827586
2           0       61  0.743902
            1       21  0.256098
3           0       83  0.488235
            1       87  0.511765
4           0       75  0.500000
            1       75  0.500000
5           0       88  0.785714
            1       24  0.214286
6           0        3  0.120000
            1       22  0.880000
```

In last pandas version is possible omit [`level`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements):

```
X['ratio'] = X['count'].div(X.groupby('day_of_week')['count'].transform('sum'))
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you ;)